# How to use a result of a select into the same select

Tags: mysql

There is a way to use a select result into the same select?

Something like this?

SELECT 10 as number, (number / 2) as half FROM table

Ty.

EDIT//////////

Ok guys,  this is the real deal.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
(SUM(
CASE 
      WHEN JVB0 = 1 AND JHIT0 = 0 AND JER0 = ' ' THEN '1' 
                WHEN JVB0 = 1 AND JHIT0 = 0 AND JER0 = '' THEN '1' 
                WHEN JVB0 = 1 AND JSF0 = 1 AND JSH0 = 1 THEN '1' 
      ELSE 0 
END)+   
SUM(CASE  
                WHEN JDP0 = 1 OR JDP0 = 2 THEN '2' 
                WHEN JDP0 = 3 OR JDP0 = 4 THEN '3' 
                WHEN JOR0 = 1 THEN '1'
                WHEN JACTB0 != '' THEN '1'
      ELSE 0 
END)) as tercios_thrown,
```

i have to put the result of tercios_thrown and a formula which uses tercios_thrown as primary number. So i think, it may be other way to do this without doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
(SUM(
CASE 
      WHEN JVB0 = 1 AND JHIT0 = 0 AND JER0 = ' ' THEN '1' 
                WHEN JVB0 = 1 AND JHIT0 = 0 AND JER0 = '' THEN '1' 
                WHEN JVB0 = 1 AND JSF0 = 1 AND JSH0 = 1 THEN '1' 
      ELSE 0 
END)+   
SUM(CASE  
                WHEN JDP0 = 1 OR JDP0 = 2 THEN '2' 
                WHEN JDP0 = 3 OR JDP0 = 4 THEN '3' 
                WHEN JOR0 = 1 THEN '1'
                WHEN JACTB0 != '' THEN '1'
      ELSE 0 
END)) as tercios_thrown,

((SUM(
CASE 
      WHEN JVB0 = 1 AND JHIT0 = 0 AND JER0 = ' ' THEN '1' 
                WHEN JVB0 = 1 AND JHIT0 = 0 AND JER0 = '' THEN '1' 
                WHEN JVB0 = 1 AND JSF0 = 1 AND JSH0 = 1 THEN '1' 
      ELSE 0 
END)+   
SUM(CASE  
                WHEN JDP0 = 1 OR JDP0 = 2 THEN '2' 
                WHEN JDP0 = 3 OR JDP0 = 4 THEN '3' 
                WHEN JOR0 = 1 THEN '1'
                WHEN JACTB0 != '' THEN '1'
      ELSE 0 
END)) / 3) as the_other_value
```

Comment: It would be trivial in this case to do `SELECT 10, 10/2`, so what are actually trying to achieve? With a better understanding of the problem, we might be able to find a solution. :)

Answer (score -1):

> It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause [or SELECT clause], because the column value might not yet be determined when the clause is executed.

So no, you can't.